# react-native ListView - I need to render only some of the objects in the DataSource

Tags: listview, react-native, render

I'm using ListView in my application.
I want to know that, is it possible, do not render all objects in listView?
My ListView is working, well. There is not any problem. I just want to stop rendering all rows.Something like in commented line that I can use?

Thank you,all.

[image]

Comment: Simply `if(rowData === 'blabla') return <View/>`

Answer (score 4):

You need to do it on a [ListViewDataSource](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html) level, not when you are rendering items. Just filter it before passing to the `ListView` `datasource` attribute:

`dataSource.cloneWithRows(items.filter((...) => 'your condition here'))`